# How to remove scrollbar in cmd ? - windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch

I am trying to make a nice looking batch program. I have already figured out how to make the cmd fullscreen. But how do i remove the anoying ugly right side scrollbar?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Right click on the title bar, select properties, then in the layout tab make sure the window height matches the screen buffer height.

[image: Example]

Comment: WHAAAAAT?! Was it really this easy? GJ

Comment: Everything is easy if you know how!

Comment: Yes this seems to be the only way... But I'm looking for a way to remember 999 lines backwards and still have no scrollbar. Is this possible?

Comment: -1 my properties had the heights the same by default, scrollbar is still there

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am on win 10

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to follow mt025's recommendation and then change the CMD into legacy mode by ticking the "Use legacy console" box.

[image: Options]

Close all console windows, start a new one and remove the legacy mode again. After another restart the scrollbar was finally gone for me. I hope this can also help others too!